# Forward's frame-dragging accelerator

Tags: general-relativity, experimental-physics, frame-dragging

On 1962, [Robert Forward studied the possibility of using General Relativity Frame-Dragging effects to accelerate probes inertially](http://u2.lege.net/culture.zapto.org_82_20080124/antigravidity/guide%20to%20antigravity.pdf) (that is, without feeling any internal G-forces)

One of the ideas is making a extremely fast and "heavy" rotator. Now, any rotator made from normal matter is limited to tangential speeds of the order of the speed of sound in the material (above that, material tensile stress cannot counter anymore the centripetal force)

One simple idea is to make the rotator capacitive, with radial charge density $q(r)$, and put an axial field $B(r)$. The rotator has radial mass density $\rho(r)$, angular speed $\omega$.

So the centripetal force on a ring slice of rotator is

$$ \rho(r) r \omega^2 $$

and if we include the Lorentz force induced by the axial field

$$ r \omega q( r ) B( r ) + r \omega^2 \rho( r) $$

the Lorentz force can counter the centripetal force as long as

$$ \frac{ q(r) }{ \rho(r) } = - \frac{ \omega}{ B(r) } $$

if we label $qm(r)$ the *charge-mass density* and make B uniform over the rotator area, we have

$$ qm( r ) = - \frac{ \omega }{ B } $$

so, for a one-meter radius rotator, to make tangential speed $0.3c$ (which allows us to ignore a bit gamma corrections), $\omega=10^8$

With an uniform field of 10 Tesla, we have that $qm = 10^7$ Coulomb per kilogram.

So I'm trying to get intuition what is expected to happen with matter at such high charge densities. Electrons are probably going to be emitted spontaneously from the capacitive rotator even in vacuum, but you can always assume that the required charge density is not achieved by adding electrons, but by *removing* them (leaving a *positive* ionic charge in the material). The Schwinger vacuum limit for the electric field seems to show up if too much charge is placed on a small volume, but the rotator stability is kept in check with a given charge-to-mass ratio, and it seems that doesn't depend directly on charge-to-volume.

> **Question:** Do you see other physical effects cropping up and destabilising the rotator? Can you explain the main effects that could
>   limit the ability to stabilise the mechanical stresses via
>   electromagnetic forces inside the rotator?

Comment: You can never get to 1e7C/kg, field emission will stop you long before that (ESPECIALLY in vacuum!). In any case, we have very good ways of accelerating matter to almost the speed of light: it's called a particle accelerator and unlike such Rube Goldberg machine designs like the one you are describing, accelerator physics is extremely well understood. If you have the money, the accelerator folks can build the machine of your dreams in no time. Do you have the money?

Comment: I guess not all minds are inclined or interested in studying frame-dragging in the lab

Comment: Also, your comment about field emission shows that you couldn't bother yourself to read the last paragraphs. Tsk, tsk

Comment: For one thing, frame dragging in GR has absolutely nothing to do with electromagnetism, for another it has been studied by the Gravity Probe B experiment which was very beautiful but failed because of technical problems. See http://einstein.stanford.edu/.

Comment: Of course I read your last paragraph, but since I am experimentalist I have a pretty good idea how much charge I can put onto a piece of mass before field emission sets it. It ain't much! :-)

Comment: So you are saying that you can't take "no" for an answer. That's not a good attitude in physics, or in life in general. Have a good one! :-)

Comment: Field emission works with electrons pal. If you make the charge density positive by *removing* electrons, there are no electrons to emit. That's on the paragraph before the last line. That's how I know you couldn't bother to read the last paragraphs

Comment: Frame dragging does not work with charge, at all. It's just a gravitational effect that, to first order, LOOKS similar to electromagnetic effects, which makes plenty of folks who don't understand the theory mistake them for each other. :-)

Comment: oh my. The charge is there to **counter** the tensile stresses of the material as the angular velocities gets above the order of the speed of sound in the material

Comment: How is that going to work? The force of the charge points to the outside of the material, not the inside. It does exactly the opposite of what you need. Why do you think there is field emission, to begin with? :-)

Comment: That's the electrostatic self-repulsion. But the magnetic force points opposite to that.. Now, I was thinking that you skipped right after reading a few lines, but now I confirm that you didn't read **anything** about the post :-)

Comment: The magnetic force doesn't do that, either. It will destabilize your rotating body in a z-pinch instability. Nice try, though. :-)

Comment: oh! it seems you have an answer for the question then. That's good. Go and enlighten us how the z-pinch instability applies on this case

Comment: Can you see now why I called this a Rube-Goldberg machine to begin with? You have to violate well known physics (which you don't seem to know) to make the concept work even in the shower. How's that for cold water? :-)

Comment: Actually that's the purpose of the question, it is right on the last line: **"or you see other physical effects cropping up and destabilising the rotator?"**,.. ah but I forgot, you didn't read any of it. That's ok

Comment: I have seen impossible physics when you began talking about 1e7C/kg with ordinary matter... the rest is just sugar coating a no-go from the start. :-)